# Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=11 "No data available for the specified predicate

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to get Number of steps taken by user today using health kit

this is my code

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let alarmTime  = Date().dayBefore
    let endTime = Date()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let obj = HealthkitManager()
        let access = obj.authorisationHealthkit()
        if(access){
    getTodaysSteps { results in
            print("no. of steps taken today \(results)")
        }}
    }
   
    func getTodaysSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
        
        let now = Date()
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        print(startOfDay)
        print(now)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
            withStart: startOfDay,
            end: now,
            options: .strictEndDate
        )
        let query1 = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate) { query, statistics, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if let sum = statistics?.sumQuantity(){
                print(statistics)
                completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
            }
            
        }
    }
            self.healthStore.execute(query1)

    }
```

I'm getting

> Access granted Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=11 "No data
> available for the specified predicate."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No data available for the specified
> predicate.}

error.

so Basically how to get today's steps taken by user?
why i am getting this error?

Comment: Your code works for me. I got the same error as you if I removed access to steps from my app in health access settings

Comment: I have given access for steps still getting same error.

Comment: Hmm. When I first ran your code and granted access to steps I got todays steps. When I turned off my app's access to steps I got exactly the result you are seeing. The error indicates that your app doesn't have access to step data. Why have you split your HealthKit access between whatever `HealthManager` is and a local `HKHealthStore` in this class. Use a single instance of `HKHealthStore`

Comment: It did not solve the problem, I have created single instance and tried